# Issue Certificates for IP addresses

Tags: remote-desktop, certificate, windows-server-2019

I have a team of just 5 people who connect using RDP. They are not connected to the my active directory, so can not connect using FQDN. I want to issue RDP certificates with IP address as a common name. Else, it gives name mismatch error. Is it possible?